# How to know that a session is expired?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

I set values to the `session` object in the method of a controller after success of login :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processLogin(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, @RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String pwd) {

        if ( utilisateurDao.verifierLoginUser(login) ) {

            if ( utilisateurDao.verifierUser(login, pwd) ) {

                HashMap<String, String> criteres = new HashMap<String, String>();
                criteres.put("user_login", login);
                criteres.put("user_passwd", pwd);
                List<Utilisateur> users = utilisateurDao.lireParCritere(criteres);
                session.setAttribute("user_code", ((Utilisateur)users.get(0)).getUser_code());

                session.setAttribute("menu", menuDao.afficherMenuParUtilisateur((Integer)session.getAttribute("user_code"), env, request, session));

                criteres.clear();
                users.clear();

                criteres.put("user_code", String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("user_code")));
                users = utilisateurDao.lireParCritere(criteres);
                session.setAttribute("user_names", ((Utilisateur)users.get(0)).getNoms());

                session.setAttribute("logout_menu", env.getProperty("menu.logout"));

                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/accueil");

            } else {

                ModelAndView modelViewLogin = new ModelAndView("redirect:/");

                modelViewLogin.addObject("e", "p").addObject("l", login);

                return modelViewLogin;

            }

        } else {

            ModelAndView modelViewLogin = new ModelAndView("redirect:/");

            modelViewLogin.addObject("e", "l");

            return modelViewLogin;

        }

    }
```

Then I opened the app inactive for some minutes. After that I went to the "accueil" path. Then the menu was not shown anymore ! The menu was got from `session`. So how to know that the `session` is expired and where is the convenient place to test it ?

Answer (score 3):

By default in spring security session is stored in `SessionRegistry`.

By using `SecurityContext` you can get this info in your controller code.

```
  SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
  Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
```

If you want to be notified when session has expired or person logged out you can always register listener on `SessionDestroyedEvent`- [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionDestroyedEvent.html).

example:

```
    @Component
    public class LogoutListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
            //do your stuff here
        }
    }
```

Its also worth to refer to [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/session-mgmt.html) for that subject.

Comment: where should I instantiate this class LogoutListener ?

Comment: Just add this as component in Spring context. In similar way that you are adding other Services or Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Interceptor,

```
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
```

In this interceptor you can control the HttpServletRequest
and check if obj exists into them and then you can throw to a new SessionExpiredException and catch with @ExceptionMapper (https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("user")==null) {
        throw new SessionExpiredException();
   }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I check like below. I think it might be help.

```
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    SecurityContext securityContext = (SecurityContext) request.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
    if(securityContext != null) {
        Authentication authentication =  securityContext.getAuthentication();
        if(null != authentication && authentication.isAuthenticated() != true) 
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```